# Writing tabular records to formatted direct access files

Tags: io, fortran

I have records similar to and I'm trying to create a formatted direct access file based on a relative Julian date (that's transform is working OK).
The record strucure is:

```
abc00 20160701 01 -99.0  -99.0  -99.0  -99.0  -99.0  -99.0  -99.0  -99.0
abc00 20160701 02 -99.0  -99.0  -99.0  -99.0  -99.0  -99.0  -99.0  -99.0
......
abc00 20160701 08 -99.0 etc . . . . . .

abc00 20160702 01 etc.
```

The `-99.0s` are symbolic of real `8F6.1` values.  I want each day's record to contain all 8 lines.

I've tried using formats like:

```
DBfmt = '(8(a5," ",i8," ",i2.2,8(" ",f8.1)," "))' or 
      = '(a5," ",i8," ",i2.2,8(" ",f8.1)," ")'
```

a file open statement of

```
 OPEN(90,FILE=MODDB(1:ld)//swmo//db, ACCESS='DIRECT',RECL=640,FORM='FORMATTED',status='new',iostat=ios)
```

and write statements like

```
write(90,DBfmt,rec=id,iostat=ios) (output(i),i=1,npr)
```

or

```
write(90,DBfmt,rec=id,iostat=ios) output(i)
```

in a loop.

I get a an error writing to unit 90 every time.
I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: What sort of error do you get?

Comment: What are the ios values?

Comment: Thanks @IanH. I only checked ios /= 0. So cannot answer your question.

Comment: I found the combination of '(8(a5," ",i8," ",i2.2,8(" ",f8.1)," "))' with recl of 720 worked OK. Despite the Intel compiler giving a record length of 1156.

Comment: You can use the IOMSG specifier to get a description of an error, or you can just remove the IOSTAT specifier and see what the Fortran processor says as it terminates the program.